# Ideals over a ring : unique factorization property

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I read a report about rings of quadratic integers $R$. This report explains that the sets $\mathcal I_R$ of ideals of $R$, (with $\times$ defined by $a\times b$ as the ideal generated by $a_i\cdot b_j$ where $a_i$ are the generators of $a$, $b_j$ the generators of $b$ and $\cdot$ the multiplication of $R$) has the property of unique factorization, even if $R$ has not.

**Does $\mathcal I_R$ have always the unique factorization property ? What properties of $R$ are needed for that ?**

Is it possible to extend $I_R$ with an operation $+$ to obtain a ring ? a principal ideal domain ?

Any reference about that subject is welcome.

Comment: First of all: Try to see yourself if in the quadratic integer case $R$ is really a ring. It isn't and it shouldn't be too hard to see why not. Just go through all the ring axioms.

Comment: The only idempotent element in a group is the identity. That is not the case for your $+$, unless we have only one ideal; if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @PaulK Ok, (I,+) is not a group, as an element a has no inverse for + in general ! I fixed my post accordingly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What properties of $R$ are needed for that?

This is a key feature of [Dedekind domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain), of which quadratic integers are an example.

> Does $\mathcal I_R$ have always the unique factorization property?

Certainly not. The property is very special. Even the ideals of $\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q$ do not satisfy unique factorization. Among domains I think unique factorization of ideals characterizes Dedekind domains.

> Is it possible to extend $\mathcal I_R$ with an operation $+$ to obtain a ring?

It depends on the monoid structure of $\mathcal I_R$ whether or not there is some random addition that makes it into a ring.

"Some random addition" isn't very interesting through since it's probably not related to $R$ at all. Now, there is already a natural binary operation to combine ideals with addition, so it is natural to ask how well that does. While ideal addition is commutative and associative and has an identity, it fails to have inverses because $I+I=I$ for every ideal. But this still gives $\mathcal I_R$ the interesting structure of a [**semiring**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring). Every ring has an associated semiring of ideals.

To make the semiring "domain-like" you would have to ask under what conditions $AB=0$ implies $A=0$ or $B=0$ for a pair of ideals $A,B$. This is equivalent to $R$ being an integral domain, so it is true for the ideal semiring of any integral domain.

I can't speak to when the semiring's ideals are principal. I am less familiar with that particular aspect of their structure.

Comment: In fact, I was interested by the property of unique factorization of Ideals on non integral domains (especially finite rings). For example, $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$ has the unique factorization property over it's non zero ideals, but it's not a Dedekind domain.

Comment: @Xoff Well, the ideals of $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$ *kind of* have unique factorization, but typically the factors aren't supposed to be "zero divisors." You can also argue that $\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^2)$ is a ring with unique factorization, if you're willing to do that.